# How I can store custom values in Joomla's "Application context"?

Tags: joomla

I just finished to implement a custom functionality in one of the page articles in my Joomla website using sorcerer. In this page it is possible to query a hash and lookup it against a database.

I would like to store the last 5 queries and show them in the page but I don't know how to do it. I need something as Java EE "Application Context" to store this values and make them available to all the users so using a Session to store this values is not what I need.

I saw in the documentation that in Joomla exists JApplicacion but none of his methods allows me to store data.

Answer (score 1):

Not having used Java, but I am pretty sure that the whole PHP platform has no "Application context". You simply need to store them in a database table.

JApplication is used to wrap up all the code that runs as the Joomla CMS. Its livetime nevertheless ends with the end of the request.

HTH, Jochen